# Facebook SSO authorize in safari but not in facebook app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

My problem: I has developed an app with Facebook SSO in my iPhone/iPad. It was working OK.

But I have changed the certificate of my app (so now it has new app ID). I also have changed the "iOS pack ID" property in Facebook: I deleted the old app ID and I added the new one.

But now my app doesn't do the Facebook SSO when Facebook app is installed. It does it OK when Facebook app is not installed and it uses Safari.

I have read [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7239291/facebook-sso-authorize-in-safari-but-not-facebook-app-in-my-iphone) and [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7572107/ios-facebook-connect-not-working-when-user-has-fbs-app-installed) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777557/facebook-sdk-ios-login-with-facebook-app-installed) that say the problem is the "iOS pack ID" and app ID don't match. I have checked it a lot of times, and it is the same.

I have put the old app ID in the "iOS pack ID" property of Facebook, but it still doesn't work.

I don't know if Facebook take a time to check if my app ID is valid, and how they show the result.

I have been a lot of time with this issue. It seem like the problem is the iOS pack ID is not exactly the app ID, but it is not the problem: they are exactly the same.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I too have been suffering from this issue all day!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it (then remove it from the question!), rather than adding to the question itself.

Comment: I will do richsage, but I cannot do it now because I have not too much reputation, so I have to wait 8 hours to reply my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I registered the app in Facebook, I put "seedID.bundleID" as iOS pack ID property. It was incorrect but unbelievable it worked. So when I wanted modify it to select the new app ID, I put the new complete ID, and it didn't work. It only worked when I put the bundle ID (only the suffix).

This makes me think that the first time a developer puts a "iOS pack ID", Facebook doesn't validate it. But the next times the iOS pack ID is modified, facebook validates it.