# Iphone : showing blank facebook login dialog

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, dialog, key

I have integrated facebook sdk in iphone app. It was working fine. But, suddenly, it stopped showing "Facebook login page" in dialog, as it is shown in screenshot. I tried it with different facebook api key, secret and it worked fine, but its not working with my old api key, secret. Please help me in this.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please check if your API keys and secrets are valid and not expired.

Comment: @BornCoder : how can I check this? I also have created new facebook api key, secret but its not working.

Comment: Please have a look at below two posts. You will get your answers there. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5683454/472344 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9137887/472344

Comment: what permissions did you set when authorizing fb?

Comment: you should accept some answers too

Comment: @jere Hi, I am ready to accept answer. Kindly, guide me how can I check what permission I have set?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem exactly the same with yours.

I managed to figure out that the user-agent I was setting is not recognized by facebook login dialog (which is a webview).

Facebook login dialog takes default user-agent, which should look like this: 
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A334. So leaving the user-agent default could be a good try.

Not sure if you still have this problem since this question has been a long while. Just to leave a message for who are facing this problem and are looking for a possible solution.