# How can I change the authentication dialog of facebook in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the facebook sdk v.3.15. When I authenticated, the Facebook App Native Login Dialog (pic 1) has been showed but I want the iOS Native Login Dialog (pic 2) to be showed. How can I do it? I have tried this link but seem it's obsolete.
[How to authorize user through a DIALOG with the NEW Facebook Connect iOS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559061/how-to-authorize-user-through-a-dialog-with-the-new-facebook-connect-ios-api/5682838#5682838)

[image: Facebook App Native Login Dialog]

[image: iOS Native Login Dialog]

Comment: It has no visual cue or privacy selector etc. why do you want to implement native iOS's login dialog?

Comment: I think the second one looks more simple than the first one, it won't require the user to switch the app to the facebook authentication dialog.